# Magento 2 : custom template file for different categories

Tags: magento2, layout, category

I want to set custom template file for different categories.

How to set custom phtml file for different categories using XML file?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to create xml file under `Your_Theme/Magento_Catalog/layout` and create file `catalog_category_view_id_{{id}}.xml`.

For ex : For creating different view for category with id 10 then, create `catalog_category_view_id_10.xml`. In that, you can call template file.

**catalog_category_view_id_10.xml :**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/custom.phtml"/>    
     </referenceContainer>
```

Hope, it will helpful for you.